# Is there a replacement for MATLAB's errorbar plot which allows brushing of data?

Tags: matlab, plot, brush

As noted in the documentation, MATLAB's [`brush`](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/brush.html) does not work with `errorbar` plots (see section *Plot Types You Cannot Brush*). For example,

```
figure;
errorbar((1:10)+2*sin(.3:.3:3),cos(1:1:10)/2);
hold all;
plot(10:-1:1,'o-g');
brush
```

generates a plot where I can brush data points from the green `plot`, but not from the red `errorbar` plot:

[image: screenshot]

**Update**

*Ideally* I would like to find a way to retroactively make plots with error bars brushable, short of extracting XData and YData and recreating a graph with `plot`.

*Failing that, is there* a function to replace `errorbar` which allows this for plots I create in the future?

Comment: I have written my own version of `errorbar` that uses `line` instead of `plot` to add errorbars. Contact me via the link in my profile if you want it.

Comment: I think I'll take you up on that offer, thanks :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plot objects created via `line` are not brushable, but those created via `plot` are. Since both objects are of type `line`, I suspect the difference might be on the level of Java.

However, this suggests a workaround: You can write a version of `errorbar` that uses the `line` command instead of the `plot` command to draw the errorbars, thus allowing you to browse just the plot.

Comment: So you are saying to use `plot` for the data points and `line` for the error bars, in contrast to `errorbar` which presumably uses `line` for both?

Comment: @Jonas Heidelberg: This is exactly what I did (plus a bunch of other things). Also, I looked at Matlab's latest `errorbar` function, and I think the solution turns out to be very simple (see edit).

Comment: That line of code is not called with my test code, only if `v6` is true. Debugging shows the line objects are actually created inside `specgraph.errorbarseries()`... but I don't see what keeps them from being brushable.

Comment: @Jonas Heidelberg: Oops, I missed that. Deleted.